# How to add apache URL rewrite for only homepage , not when having request URI

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I add this rewrite rule to redirect http to https. However, in my ecommerce website, only homepage and checkout page need https, not other

```
pageRewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

After i add this rule, all pages are redirected to https, not just homepage. What should i change to redirect only homepage?

thank you